# Why does num_glyphs not match the number of glyphs enumerated by FT_Get_First_Char / FT_Get_Next_Char

Tags: python, freetype, freetype2, freetype-py

Consider the following example. It uses `freetype` (through a [python wrapper](https://freetype-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to load a font and then counts the `glyphs`.

```
import freetype as FT
f = FT.Face('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Hack-Regular.ttf')
f.num_glyphs
# 1573
len([*f.get_chars()])
# 1549
```

As you can see the number obtained by counting does not match the number reported by the library when asked directly.

Why?

Note: Knowledge of the python wrapper shouldn't be necessary to address this question. The python functions used here are thin wrappers around functions from the C-API. The relevant bits are

`get_chars` uses `FT_Get_First_Char` and `FT_Get_Next_Char` to loop through all (?) characters provided

```
    charcode, agindex = self.get_first_char()
    yield charcode, agindex
    while agindex != 0:
        charcode, agindex = self.get_next_char(charcode, 0)
        yield charcode, agindex
```

`num_glyphs` just pulls up its namesake

```
num_glyphs = property(lambda self: self._FT_Face.contents.num_glyphs,
...
```

Comment: I'm not a font expert, but from functions like `FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex` I would say there are variant glyphs that correspond to the same code point, so there will be more glyphs that code points.

Comment: @MarkTolonen expert enough to find in five minutes what I couldn't in a day. Thank you very much!