# What is the meaning of "uniE0A1" as returned by FT_Get_Glyph_Name?

Tags: python, unicode, freetype, freetype2, freetype-py

This is question is probably the product of my not understanding something fundamental, but I could really do with some help, so here goes.

While trying to wrap my head around text rendering, freetype etc. I came across those strange glyphs that as I undestand it report themselves to be associated with a unicode code point, but when I check from the unicode side, that code point is not valid.

For example, using the font "Hack" the glyph at index 1437 is an example of these mystery glyphs, see below for what it looks like.

Here is some demonstration code using the `freetype-py` python wrapper of `freetype`.

First, as an example for what looks plausible and applies to >99% of glyphs let's look at letter `"A"`:

```
import numpy as np
import freetype as FT
import unicodedata

ff = FT.Face('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Hack-Regular.ttf')
ff.set_char_size(12<<6)

ff.load_glyph(1425)
ff.get_glyph_name(1425)
# b'uni0041'
```

hex 41 is decimal 65 which is ascii/unicode for 'A', and the rendered bitmap also looks 'A'.

```
np.array(ff.glyph.bitmap.buffer).reshape(-1,8)
# array([[  0,   0,  67, 255, 121,   0,   0,   0],
#        [  0,   0, 143, 213, 198,   0,   0,   0],
#        [  0,   0, 218,  85, 250,  21,   0,   0],
#        [  0,  38, 248,   9, 203,  95,   0,   0],
#        [  0, 115, 191,   0, 136, 171,   0,   0],
#        [  0, 191, 125,   0,  69, 242,   5,   0],
#        [ 15, 250, 252, 252, 252, 255,  68,   0],
#        [ 87, 231,   2,   0,   0, 178, 145,   0],
#        [162, 152,   0,   0,   0,  97, 221,   0]])
unicodedata.name(chr(0x0041))
# 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'
```

now let's do the same for glyph index 1437:

```
ff.load_glyph(1437)
ff.get_glyph_name(1437)
# b'uniE0A1'
np.array(ff.glyph.bitmap.buffer).reshape(-1,5)
# array([[ 56,  70,   0,   0,   0],
#        [112, 140,   0,   0,   0],
#        [112, 140,   0,   0,   0],
#        [112, 140,   0,   0,   0],
#        [112, 140,   0,   0,   0],
#        [112, 140,   0,   0,   0],
#        [105, 232, 224, 178,   0],
#        [  0, 168, 150,  40, 216],
#        [  0, 168, 241,  46, 216],
#        [  0, 168, 223, 124, 216],
#        [  0, 168, 131, 215, 216],
#        [  0, 168,  81, 212, 216],
#        [  0, 168,  84, 108, 216]])
unicodedata.name(chr(0xE0A1))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# ValueError: no such name
```

So, the glyph calls itself "uniE0A1" but as I said unicode has no code point there (I double-checked and it is not in `UnicodeData.txt` (version 12 I think)) and I do not recognize the bitmap.

This question is loosely related to [Why does num_glyphs not match the number of glyphs enumerated by FT_Get_First_Char / FT_Get_Next_Char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56715162/7207392) , another example of things not adding up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code point U+E0A1 lies in a Private Use area.  A font can use it for custom characters.

https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I didn't expect anything resembling humor from this rather dry subject matter but the file you linked is hilarious, a truly invaluable document. From a practical point of view would you say I can safely ignore those guys? Also, as you seem knowledgeable, would you mind having a quick look at my other question I linked?

Comment: @PaulPanzer No! You can NOT safely ignore the guys at unicode.org.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed hack-fonts-3.003 and inspected the glyph produced from the character made from codepoint U+E0A1:

[image: latin capital letter L over latin capital letter N]

This character is used as a line number indicator in [powerline enabled applications](https://powerline.readthedocs.io). Since the character currently lives in a private use area, its meaning is dissociated from its appearance. In other words, you can only deduct the character's meaning if you already know what it is from how it looks like. I know what it is (because I'm familiar with the subject matter), you (OP) don't.

Therefore, in order to solve that problem, there exists a [proposal to include powerline characters into Unicode proper](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2019/19068-powerline-syms.pdf). Once the proposal is adopted, expect fonts and applications to switch over from the nameless and meaningless `U+E0A1 ‹›` to `U+2FE1 ‹⿡› \N{LINE NUMBER INDICATOR}`.

---

`uniE0A1` is a badly named identifier in the font, the font author was lazy or careless. It should be called `line_number_indicator` or have a similar meaningful name.